# SendGrid Port 8080 Deprecation

Tags: c#, sendgrid-api-v3

We've received an email from SendGrid support stating that API calls will no longer be accepted on port 8080.  We use the SendGrid C# SDK to make API calls, I can't see where to set the port.  Can somebody tell me the port number the SendGrid C# SDK uses, please?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: You will want to use 443 which is a standard port so you can just remove the port from the url. BTW, SendGrid has a support system.

Comment: Thanks.  I submitted a support ticket to SendGrid but didn't get a reply.

Comment: Read vendor website to for SMTP settings.  Just using Port 443 is not enough is you are sending emails.  SMTP cannot be used to receive emails.  The vendor may require you to configure a POP mail account on your Windows User Mail settings.

Comment: @jdweng OP is talking about their API which is not smtp and does not require, nor can it even use, a pop client.

Comment: @Crowcodeer : What is email?

Comment: @jdweng I am familiar with SendGrid and it's API. It is just REST calls. SendGrid deals with the actual email protocols for you.

Comment: @Crowcoder :  If it does everything then why specify port 443?  Why not port 587?  What was wrong with my response?

Comment: @jdweng I'm just saying it simply uses HTTPS. There is generally no need to specify a port.